# Unable to build code I copied from an article

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

I have [this code](http://monobin.com/__d548b1bf1) that I copied from [Mike Bluestein's article](http://mikebluestein.wordpress.com/2009/12/11/sending-mail-from-an-iphone-app-with-monotouch/) on sending e-mail from an app. Unfortunately, I get the following error on line 5:

```
Unexpected symbol 'public'
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The code you copied is **completely** different from the original code, and is very far from C#. Before you start with esoteric platforms and advanced code examples, why not get a book on the basics of C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added a link to the sample project at the bottom of the [blog post](http://mikebluestein.wordpress.com/2009/12/11/sending-mail-from-an-iphone-app-with-monotouch/). I hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

You copied it into a method. The code you copied defines a member variable at a class level and then a couple methods.

It looks to be just a sample taken out of a larger codebase, so even if you just paste it into a class, it probably still won't work as you expect (if at all). Instead of blindly copy/pasting you want to read through the article and the example to understand what it's doing and then replicate it in your own code.

I second Konrad's suggestion: you may want to brush up on C# first.